# Submit form with AJAX and send data to file as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, forms

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. I want to submit a form and store its data in a file as JSON. I've got to find part of the solution, using PHP to store the data into a file, but now I want to avoid redirection after the form is submitted.

**HTML**

```
<form action="saveit.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group" id="vaga-group">
        <label for="vaga">Job</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vaga" name="vaga" placeholder="Ex.: UX Designer, Desenvolvedor Java">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="cidade-group">
        <label for="cidade">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="Ex. São Paulo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="tipo-group">
        <label for="tipo">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="tipo" id="tipo">
            <option>Full time</option>
            <option>Freelance</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**saveit.php**

```
<?php
    $filetxt = 'js/list.json';

    $formdata = array(
        'vaga'=> $_POST['vaga'],
        'cidade'=> $_POST['cidade'],
        'tipo'=> $_POST['tipo']
    );

    $arr_data = array();  
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $arr_data[] = $formdata;
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents('js/list.json', $jsondata);

    $form_state['redirect'] = false;

?>
```

By submitting exactly at it is right now my **list.json** file is updated with new information, as seen below:

```
[
    {
        "vaga": "Desenvolvedor Front-End",
        "cidade": "New York",
        "tipo": "Freelance"
    },
    {
        "vaga": "Desenvolvedor Java",
        "cidade": "Chicago",
        "tipo": "Freelance"
    }
]
```

Now I want to stop the redirection from happening after the form is submitted, using AJAX. I understand that because I'm using **action="saveit.php"** it is redirecting to that file (or to wherever I pointed out in that file), but I'm failing to find the proper use of AJAX to validate and submit the form without redirection.

I've found tons of examples of AJAX code to stop redirection, but none of them let me keep storing new data into list.json after submission, and that's the problem. Please, help!
Thank you!

Comment: And you didn't find an answer in here? I'm sure this was asked already...

Comment: @Daenu I didn't. Like I said, I've found many AJAX examples showing how to stop redirection, but I didn't manage to keep storing data into list.json. That's the problem!

Comment: So either you submit the form via Ajax and cancel the submission or you redirect the .php back to the page you were on. The PHP code should not be any different when the data is submitted via Ajax.

Comment: @epascarello So those are the only options? With Ajax I'll fail to update list.json and I'll have to stick the a .php-only submission?

Comment: No with Ajax it will NOT fail to update the list... The php is NO different when it is an Ajax call. Heck the php has no clue it came from an Ajax call. With Ajax you need to serialize the form fields, send it up the values, and cancel the form submission.

Comment: @epascarello ok, and what would be the code to successfully do that? That's the issue I'm facing and failing to solve.

Comment: What have you tried that failed? You build up a string of values to post to the server, you create an XMLHttpRequest, you send up the data.

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_5_–_Working_with_data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_5_–_Working_with_data)

Comment: Not hard to find tutorials regarding submitting forms with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get rid of the forms `action`
2. Using jQuery (orXMLHTTPRequest if you are feeling bold)

(pop it in a `<script>` tag)

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
  $.post('saveit.php', {
    vaga: document.getElementById('vaga').value,      // all the values you
    cidade: document.getElementById('cidade').value,  // want to send
    // and so on ...
  }).done(function(result){
    // result = server result
    // do what you must to notify client here
  }).fail(function(err){
    // oh dear ... error. tell user
  })
}
```

3. change HTML `button`

`<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick='ajaxSubmit()'>Send</button>`